# RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, servlets

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("https://app.inpostlinks.com/login").forward(request, response);
```

I want to forward the request to the foreign URL like `https://app.inpostlinks.com/login`, not residing on the container where the servlet resides.

It's not getting forwarded. Are there any solutions on the above scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forwarding is for passing say a servlets request and response to a JSP to do the presentation of the result of some business logic.

If you want to pass the user to a different website, you need to do a "redirect" instead of a "forward", ie get the server to return a 301 code and a location:

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```